# In-App-Purchase - restore purchases

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, in-app-purchase, mac-app-store

I'm having some problems when submitting my macOS app which has in-app-purchases set-up, they rejected my app because i don't have a restore purchase button.

I need a suggestion about where to put that button. What I'm thinking is that i should add that functionality when the app is re-installed, and in the menu bar, where the app name is ( where quit app is ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great movie about where and how to put restore button. This is made by Apple for WWDC so it's clear what excatly they wants. This is for iOS, but idea is the same.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/ios/?id=3 <- here you go. Move to **27:30**